# Importing whitespace delimited CSV with empty columns at the end of the line

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a whitespaced CSV that looks as following:

```
Welcome
Test
2022-07-17 05:00:00 AM
Itemt1 Item2 Item3
1 2 3
```

I am attempting to import into Pandas, but I am unable since the lines that have empty columns at the end do not have whitespaces to account for these empty columns. They just jump to the next line.

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter='\s+', encoding='utf-16-le')
```

And this is the error that I am give:

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 471

Comment: 1) you probably want `skiprows=3`  to skip the headers. 2) your data is corrupted as one of the lines has too many spaces (a cell has a sentence instead of a word?). You'll have to figure out which line it is and fix it manually.

Comment: The issue is that it is a rather large file and it gets pulled automatically weekly. The problem is that the lines that have empty columns at the end, don't have whitespaces at the end of the line to account for the empty columns

Comment: Opening the file in Excel and saving it as a regular csv fixes all the issues @QuangHoang

Comment: Then probably your exposition here is not really accurate.

Comment: I believe the confusion is that the 1st 3 rows look like header rows (welcome, description, timestamp). The data begins on row 3 (continues on row 4). But both row 3 and 4 depict 3 elements. The first comment suggesting `skiprows` will fix the headers being counted as rows. The question is, do other data rows have different counts of elements? If so, to solve this, more info about the file and assumptions may be needed.